# Cabal configure can't find an installed package inside a cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I've made a cabal sandbox, installed a package to it, yet `runhaskell Setup configure` complains that the package dependency that I just installed is missing.

I verified the package name and version and that's okay.
Running `cabal install --dependencies-only` says "all the requested packages are already installed".

What's going on & how can I fix it?

If relevant I've encountered this with QuickCheck-2.7.5 on Windows 7 with cabal-install 1.20.0.3 using cabal 1.20.0.1 and ghc 7.6.3.

---

Configuring through `runhaskell Setup configure` outputs:

> Configuring MyPackage-0.1.0.0...
>   Setup.hs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
>   QuickCheck ==2.7.5

Comment: What does `cabal configure` say ?

Comment: you're running `Setup.hs` with `runhaskell`, have you tried just running `cabal build`?  That'll do nothing but compile your project with your configuration in your `.cabal` file.  IIRC `runhaskell` is just a wrapper around `ghc` and is agnostic of `cabal`.

Comment: Instead of running `runhaskell Setup configure`, you should do `cabal configure`. `runhaskell` doesn't know about sandboxes.

Comment: @user2407038 Solved my issue, thank you! Perhaps post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of running `runhaskell Setup configure`, you should do `cabal configure`. `runhaskell` doesn't know about sandboxes.